# Find the minimum value of $x^2 + 4xy + 4y^2 + 2z^2$ given that $xyz = 32$

Tags: inequality, solution-verification

I had a go at this question and believed my answer and solution to be correct, but it turned out not to be.

Here it is: ($x, y,  z$ are all greater than 0.)

[image: Notice that <code>$\x^2 + 4xy + 4y^2$</code>]

This solution gives the incorrect answer and I not too sure why.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Are $x,y,z$ positive? Because you can't use AM/GM if $x+2y=0$, for example...

Comment: Yes, all $x, y, z$ are positive.

Comment: It's wrong to say that "the minimum value of $(x+2y)^2$ is $8xy$. It *is* the minimum value, given you know $xy$, but there is no minimum value, in general, and the infimum of $(x+2y)^2$ in this space is $0$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that x, y, z are all greater than 0 therefore, it can't be 0.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/867793/find-the-maximum-value-of-xy2z3-given-that-x2-y2-z2-1-using

Answer (score 7):

HINT:

As $x,y,z>0$ using AM,GM inequality,

$$\frac{x^2+2xy+4y^2+2xy+z^2+z^2}6\ge(x^2\cdot  2xy\cdot  4y^2\cdot  2xy\cdot  z^2\cdot z^2)^{\dfrac16}$$

Comment: Thank you, I eventually came to this solution, however I am still don't quite understand why my solution is incorrect? Could you offer some help with that?

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: Shouldn't it be $4y^2$ not $y^2$? This also makes it solvable.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews, The typo has been rectified

Comment: @Semiclassical, Thanks for your observation

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the notion that the minimum value of $(x+2y)^2$ is $8xy.$ That is only true *once you know $xy$.* The infimum of all values $(x+2y)^2$ in the domain $xyz=32, x,y,z>0$ is clearly zero.

Alternatively, you assumed $(x+2y)^2=8xy$, but that's only true when $x=2y$, which is a restriction you dropped in the remainder of your answer.

Now, given $z$, we have $xy=\frac{32}{z}$, so $(x+2y)^2 \geq 8xy = \frac{256}{z}$. So we are trying to minimize:

$$f(z)=2z^2 +\frac{256}{z}$$

Comment: Thanks for your help! Could you please explain why the infimum of all values is 0, as x,y,and are greater than 0?

Comment: I didn't say minimum, I said "infimum." Given $\epsilon>0$ you can set $$x=y=\frac{\sqrt{\epsilon}}4$$ and then $(x+2y)^2<\epsilon$.

Comment: Okay, I understand. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Correct me if I'm wrong but it appears you evaluated the AM-GM inequality incorrectly. By AM-GM:

$$\frac{x^2+4xy+4y^2}{3}\ge\sqrt[3]{16x^3y^3}$$
$$x^2+4xy+4y^2\ge6xy\sqrt[3]{2}$$

Comment: No, you are wrong, it is shorthand for $\frac{x+2y}{2}\geq \sqrt{x\cdot 2y}$ implies $(x+2y)^2\geq 8xy$.

Comment: Ah, I see my mistake, thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Use AM-GM!

$x^2+4xy+4y^2+2z^2=x^2+2xy+2xy+4y^2+z^2+z^2\geq 6\sqrt[6]{x^2(2xy)^24y^2(z^2)^2}=6\sqrt[6]{16(xyz)^4}=96.\\$Equality if and only if $x=z=4$ and $y=2$.